# Long list variable slowing flutter app performance

Tags: list, performance, flutter

When I try to use a list of 14216 maps, this widget freezes for a few seconds during initialization:

```
List _list = [
  {
    "code": "110000000",
    "region": "11",
    "district": "0",
    "locality_center": "0",
    "locality": "0",
    "ru_name": "Акмолинская область",
    "kk_name": "Ақмола облысы"
  },...];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('it takes a few seconds before this message is printed in terminal');
    print(_list.length);
    return Container();
}
```

Is there a better way of storing and using huge lists in flutter?

Comment: do you try to display all list items as a part of your UI ?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "access"? When it is getting slow?

Comment: @glavigno displaying in ListView is fine, the initialization itself takes a lot of time

Comment: @camillo777 by access I meant printing its length or displaying the name of an element. It gets slow at the very start during initialization

Comment: @Darkhan you should show the other code, it is normal that when app is starting takes some time to initialise itself; how are you measuring the app performance?

Comment: @camillo777 it clearly freezes when I navigate to the screen where the huge list is initialized

Comment: Hello @Darkhan, ho do you create the list?

Comment: Put the list in a static class in a different file.

Comment: @camillo777 I tried that, it didn't help